# issue adding licensing library to my project

Tags: android, gson, android-lvl

Following the instructions at [Setting up for licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html) "Creating the LVL as a library project."

I created the library project as per the very vague instructions as I already had the LVL libs installed in the SDK manager.  The console log pasted below (it's sooo hard to paste stuff in SO) is complaining about (I think) the two android-support-v4.jar files (one in my project and the other in my the libs project) don't match.

Also now my imports for all things GSON are invalid causing dozens of errors.

I'm targeting gingerbread 2.33.

What is causing all of this damage?

```
2013-02-11 17:30:22 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-02-11 17:30:22 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-02-11 17:30:22 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-02-11 17:30:22 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Versions found are:
[2013-02-11 17:30:22 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Path: D:\_DBAWorkspace\LVLLib\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-02-11 17:30:22 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity]  Length: 385685
[2013-02-11 17:30:22 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity]  SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2013-02-11 17:30:22 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Path: D:\_DBAWorkspace\com.deanblakely.PSActivity\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-02-11 17:30:22 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity]  Length: 349252
[2013-02-11 17:30:22 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity]  SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
[2013-02-11 17:30:22 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2013-02-11 17:30:25 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-02-11 17:30:25 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-02-11 17:30:25 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-02-11 17:30:25 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Versions found are:
[2013-02-11 17:30:25 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Path: D:\_DBAWorkspace\LVLLib\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-02-11 17:30:25 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity]  Length: 385685
[2013-02-11 17:30:25 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity]  SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2013-02-11 17:30:25 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Path: D:\_DBAWorkspace\com.deanblakely.PSActivity\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-02-11 17:30:25 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity]  Length: 349252
[2013-02-11 17:30:25 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity]  SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
[2013-02-11 17:30:25 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2013-02-11 17:34:32 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-02-11 17:34:32 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-02-11 17:34:32 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-02-11 17:34:32 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Versions found are:
[2013-02-11 17:34:32 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Path: D:\_DBAWorkspace\LVLLib\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-02-11 17:34:32 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity]  Length: 385685
[2013-02-11 17:34:32 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity]  SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2013-02-11 17:34:32 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Path: D:\_DBAWorkspace\com.deanblakely.PSActivity\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-02-11 17:34:32 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity]  Length: 349252
[2013-02-11 17:34:32 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity]  SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
[2013-02-11 17:34:32 - com.deanblakely.PSActivity] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the log cat says there are two different versions of support library. Please replace android-support-v4.jar library from your project with the android-support-v4.jar file from the library project that way you will have the same versions of compatible library file in your project and dependent library project(s). To do that, **in the Package Explorer**:

- go to libs folder of your library project --> right click on android-support-v4.jar --> select 'copy'
- go to your project --> right click on libs folder --> choose 'paste' --> click 'yes' to overwrite existing file.
- clean your project

Comment: I had guessed that doing this or the reverse would make them match but I'm wondering now if I have a better jar or a worse jar.  I see that when I look at the properties of a jar there is no 'version' (like there is on my home planet, C#).  Anyway that did the trick to eliminate the mismatch.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: Well, Then I would keep the file that has the bigger size. You are welcome!